# Splitting PDF document into multiple documents

Tags: pdfbox

I'm trying to split a PDF document into multiple documents where each document includes the maximum number of pages it can contain where the file size is less than a maximum file size.

My code currently works when running from Eclipse, but when I click on the .jar file, the static method in a java class seems to crash (I can't seem to catch an exception however).

The code that isn't working is:

myListOfDocuments=mysplitter.split(document);

Somehow the JVM bails on the static method when the above line is called.  The load seems to work fine, as follows:
PDDocument document=PDDocument.load(aFile);

Any ideas?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class PDFMaxSizeSplitter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static ArrayList<File> splitTheFile(File aFile,long maxSize){

        ArrayList<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        //Checks to see if file is already small enough
        if (aFile.length() <= maxSize){
            resultFiles.add(aFile);
            return resultFiles;
        }

        //checks to see if it's a directory
        if (aFile.isDirectory()){
            resultFiles.add(aFile);
            return resultFiles;
        }

        try {

            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(aFile);
            Splitter mysplitter = new Splitter();
            List<PDDocument> myListOfDocuments = mysplitter.split(document);
            int docNumber = 0;
            while (myListOfDocuments.size()>0){
                long theResults = 0;
                theResults = getChunk(myListOfDocuments,0,(long) (myListOfDocuments.size()-1),maxSize);
                PDDocument newPDFDoc = new PDDocument();
                for (long pageindex=0; pageindex<=theResults; pageindex++){
                    newPDFDoc.addPage(myListOfDocuments.get((int) pageindex).getPage(0)); 
                }
                File newFile = new File(aFile.getParentFile() +
                                        File.separator +
                                        aFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "") +
                                        "Part" +
                                        String.format("%03d", docNumber) +
                                        ".pdf");
                //System.out.println(newFile.getCanonicalFile());
                newPDFDoc.save(newFile);
                resultFiles.add(newFile);
                myListOfDocuments=myListOfDocuments.subList((int) (theResults)+1, (myListOfDocuments.size()));
                newPDFDoc.close();
                docNumber++;
            }

            document.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return resultFiles;
        }

    private static long getChunk(List<PDDocument> thePages, long lowPage, long highPage, long maxSize) throws IOException{
        //System.out.println("low " + lowPage + " high page: " + highPage);
        if ( (highPage-lowPage)<=1 ){
            if(PDFMaxSizeSplitter.testSize(thePages,0,highPage)<=maxSize){
                return highPage;
            } else{
                return lowPage;
            }

        } else if (PDFMaxSizeSplitter.testSize(thePages, 0,lowPage+ (highPage-lowPage)/2)<=maxSize){
            return PDFMaxSizeSplitter.getChunk(thePages, lowPage + (highPage-lowPage)/2, highPage,maxSize);
        }
            else {
                return PDFMaxSizeSplitter.getChunk(thePages, lowPage, lowPage + (highPage-lowPage)/2,maxSize);
            }
    }

    private static long testSize(List<PDDocument> thePages, long start, long stop) throws IOException{
        //System.out.println("Trying: " + (new Long(start)).toString() + " to " + (new Long(stop)).toString()); 
        PDDocument testerdocument = new PDDocument();
        //Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile((new Long(start)).toString(), (new Long(stop)).toString());
        //System.out.println("Creating tempPath " +tempPath.toString());    
        //File tempFile=new File(tempPath.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream tempFile = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (long pageindex=start; pageindex<=stop; pageindex++){
            testerdocument.addPage(thePages.get((int) pageindex).getPage(0)); 
        }
        testerdocument.save(tempFile);
        long thefilesize = tempFile.size();
        //long thefilesize =  (tempFile.length());
        //Files.deleteIfExists(tempPath);
        tempFile.reset();
        testerdocument.close();
        return thefilesize;
    }
}
```

-----------edit--------------

It turns out the JVM was running out of memory.

Comment: 1) splitter.split is not static 2) please include a bit more code 3) what version of PDFBox and of java are you using?

Comment: Are the PDFBox jar files in your classpath when running it outside eclipse?

Comment: Re exections - don't click on the jar file, run it from the command line: java -jar xxx.jar

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Considering the resolution (the JVM was running out of memory) it might be appropriate to offer a different way to use the `Splitter`, e.g. using a new method `public void split(PDDocument document, Consumer<PDDocument>)` which forwards each split document as soon as it is created and discards it thereafter to keep the memory footprint low. (Or something similar if Java8 specific stuff is not yet wanted in PDFBox.)

Comment: How would that be done?  There is no constructor for this version of split.  Wouldn't this involve rewriting split altogether. PDDocument can be created with new PDDocument(aFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());  Does this keep everything on the hard drive?  Thereafter, I have created the array to be new PDDocument documents with this memory setting.

Comment: @mkl we're still at jdk6... and people could simply use addPage on an empty PDDocument. I'd rather work on nastier problems, e.g. the one about importPage that you pointed out (thanks).

Comment: @LoveToCode *Wouldn't this involve rewriting split altogether.* - that's why I directed that comment at Tilman - he is one of the main PDFBox contributors.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *I'd rather work on nastier problems, e.g. the one about importPage* - *grin* probably the person who made it work in `Splitter` should instead have fixed the actual `importPage`... but I'd still propose adding a Jira task for a less resource hungry split implementation, even if at low priority.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the JVM was running out of memory.  I added a jvm argument to increase the memory.  Also, I switched to the 64 bit jvm mode by using the argument -d64 on the jvm.  Also, I have been using the disk drive cached memory management found in pdfbox, e.g., new PDDocument(aFile, MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

With these settings, I can handle several gigabytes of files.  Now in the code, I try to load the documents into direct memory and catch the out of memory exception to switch to a low memory mode.  In the low memory mode I use the MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly() to avoid using too much of the heap.